Question about MOCA and MEA
Why is there sometimes a MOCA on the chart and sometimes only an MEA?
In the picture, there's only an MEA until BAGBY, and then MOCA appears after BAGBY. Do you know why this is happening?


Per the FAA defintion of MOCA, the service volume is limited to a 22 NM radius around a VOR.  So while it is possible to fly safely at 6,600 ft and navigate using GPS signals, pilots must use 8,500 ft minimum when navigating by VOR signals.
For those airways where MOCA is omitted, it is effectively equal to the MEA.
References:

FAA-H-8083-16B Instrument Procedures Handbook
FAA PCG Pilot/Controller Glossary
14 CFR § 91.177 Minimum altitudes for IFR operations.
14 CFR § 95 IFR Altitudes

